# WebApi - CurrentUserId isn't accessible until after Registration?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    // Attempt to register the user
                    try
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                        WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                        InitiateDatabaseForNewUser(model.UserName);

                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);

                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

In this code, CurrentUserId (at the very end) always resolves to -1 because WebSecurity doesn't see the new user until after the method closes.  I'd like to return a profile or at least the id of the newly registered user from the Register() method - how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you seen this SO post about setting LoginCreatedUser and DisableCreatedUser in the CreateUserWizard ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134638/what-does-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-do

Comment: Thanks AardVark- I haven't specified either LoginCreatedUser="false" or DisableCreatedUser="true" in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the ID of the user like this:

```
WebSecurity.GetUserId(model.UserName)
```