# return RedirectToAction not redirecting from Login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect back to my Home/Index page after a successful Active Directory login using PricipalContext(ContextType.Domain) to validate the credentials.  I can see that the credentials are being successfully validated, however the page just seems to reload and clears out my username and password instead of redirecting to the Index page that cooresponds to my Home Controller.  Everything I see implies using return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") but doesn't seem to work for me.

web.config - You can see that it takes you to the login page by default

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2080" cookieless="UseCookies"></forms>
</authentication>
```

HomeController

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

LoginController

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
string user = form["user"] as string;
string password = form["password"] as string;
string[] userInfo = user.Split('/');

if ((userInfo.Length > 2) || (userInfo.Length < 2))
{
    ViewBag.Message = "You must enter Domain and Username in Domain/User format.";
    return View("Index");
}
else
{
   using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, userInfo[0]))
{
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(userInfo[1], password);

    if (isValid)
    {
here. 
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Credentials. Maximum of 3 attempts before lock out.";
        return View("Index");
    }
}
}
}
```

If you need me to provide anything else I can. I know there is somehting I am doing wrong here but I can't figure out why it keeps redirectingback to login instead of ~/Home/Index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorize attribute expects the form authorization cookie to be setup.  When the user is successfully logged in, you need to call:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userInfo[1], false);
```

see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b(v=vs.110).aspx) on the signature of the method.  Also a useful read: [What does FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134638/what-does-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-do).

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you.  So basically it was just waiting for the authorization to set a cookie.  I will read the documentation you provided to understand more. Thanks again.